# Yolov4 Darknet Training Error on Macbook Pro M1

Tags: tensorflow, opencv, apple-m1, yolo, darknet

I am creating a custom Yolov4 to detect characters & digits in an image. I have installed Darknet on my Macbook M1 referring to this repo: https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet

The annotated dataset is ready for training. However, when the training beings, an error is shown saying that the GPU and OpenCV are not being used and the training stops abruptly.

Here is the error in the terminal:

```
GPU isn't used 
OpenCV isn't used - data augmentation will be slow 
valid: Using default 'data/train.txt'
yolov4-obj
mini_batch = 4, batch = 64, time_steps = 1, train = 1 
   layer   filters  size/strd(dil)      input                output
   0 conv     32       3 x 3/ 1    416 x 416 x   3 ->  416 x 416 x  32 0.299 BF
   1 conv     64       3 x 3/ 2    416 x 416 x  32 ->  208 x 208 x  64 1.595 BF
   2 conv     64       1 x 1/ 1    208 x 208 x  64 ->  208 x 208 x  64 0.354 BF
   3 route  1                                  ->  208 x 208 x  64 
   4 conv     64       1 x 1/ 1    208 x 208 x  64 ->  208 x 208 x  64 0.354 BF
   5 conv     32       1 x 1/ 1    208 x 208 x  64 ->  208 x 208 x  32 0.177 BF
   6 conv     64       3 x 3/ 1    208 x 208 x  32 ->  208 x 208 x  64 1.595 BF
                                     ......
                                     ......

Total BFLOPS 59.817 
avg_outputs = 494379 
Loading weights from yolov4.conv.137...
 seen 64, trained: 0 K-images (0 Kilo-batches_64) 
Done! Loaded 137 layers from weights-file 
Learning Rate: 0.001, Momentum: 0.949, Decay: 0.0005
 Detection layer: 139 - type = 28 
 Detection layer: 150 - type = 28 
 Detection layer: 161 - type = 28 
Resizing, random_coef = 1.40 

 608 x 608 
 Create 64 permanent cpu-threads 

 mosaic=1 - compile Darknet with OpenCV for using mosaic=1 

 mosaic=1 - compile Darknet with OpenCV for using mosaic=1
```

Opencv is installed using `brew install opencv@2` and M1 GPU works fine with TensorFlow. But due to some reasons, it is simply not working here.

Any help on this issue will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!